# What's with the random small bonuses for Terran?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

You know, like the extra 5 health on SCVs and the 1 extra supply given from a Command Center? At least with units like the missile turret it makes sense for it to be a bit better as far as attack since it can't shoot ground (unlike it's counterparts).

Comment: Spore crawlers also can't shoot ground. Only Protoss cannons can hit both.

Comment: Questions about balance are usually questions that are [not based on an actual problem](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). See ["Why did They design it that way, anyway?", and why do we allow or disallow these?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-these) for more information...

Comment: *cough*my problem is that I don't understand why it is that way*cough* (i wouldn't ask a question if I didn't have a problem >.<)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Juan Manuel's answer is the correct answer in the general case. You have to look at each race as a whole to evaluate balance, not the individual specifics. A 1v1 comparison between an SCV and a probe (or a zealot vs. a marine, or a cannon vs. a turret) may make it seem like one race has a "bonus," but SC2 isn't a game of SCVs vs. drones, it's a game of race vs. race.

As for the specific cases:

- An SCV has 5 more health, but drones regenerate and probes regain shields. This makes them better at worker harassment and marginally better at scouting. Probes also can warp in buildings without stopping; drones can be built many at a time with larva injection, and SCV's can repair. They are all unique units.
- Command Centers may provide more supply, but Hatcheries cost far less to produce, and Nexuses can be built without requiring the worker to stay there. Also, Zerg overloads provide supply, but also scouting, map vision, creep, detection, and transport with the right upgrades.

My point is not that "Terran bonuses are actually not as good as Zerg/Protoss;" my point is that each race has lots of unique strengths and liabilities, lots of units and upgrades that are great at some things and weak at others.

The point of SC2 strategy and tactics is to discern these strengths and weaknesses, and use them to one's best advantages to win the game.

Answer (score 4):

Balancing 3 complete different races is not easy.

Keep in mind that they are not bonuses, they are traits from the race; the Zerg and Protoss also have things the other races do not; just as an example, regeneration for the first, shields and Warpgates for the second.

If the races didn't have these differences you'd end up basically with the same 3, just with different skins; kind of the orcs and the humans on Warcraft 2.

Comment: To be fair, the ranged units in warcraft2 had different upgrades! /s

Comment: Also, spellcasters had different spells! :)